# Polynominal equation with 6 on roots and integer variables

Tags: roots, cubics

The polynomial equation $x^3 - ax^2 + bx - c = 0$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers, and it has $6$ as on of its roots. According to the rational root theorem, what is the value of $c$?

The answer is $18$, but I'm struggling with how to get there. Can someone show me the steps to solve this? I'm trying to use the Rational Root Theorem but doing it in a reverse order? Confused.

Comment: $0 = (x-1)(x-1)(x-6) = x^3 - 8x^2 + 13x - 6$ matches the equation and has $6$ as one of its roots, but $c \neq 18$

Comment: How did you come up with the coefficients for this?

Comment: I still need help with the steps arriving to this.

Comment: I've just picked a polynomial with roots $x_{1,2} = 1, x_3 = 6$ and the leading coefficient equal to 1. Just a counter-example for the statement that $c = 18$. Maybe the problem statement had something you've forgotten to mention?